# Is there a way to make an object from an ArrayList that is independent of the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

For example:

```
ArrayList<SomeObj> list = new ArrayList<SomeObj>();
SomeObj temp = list.get(0); // this points to the first object and 
//any modification to it will be reflected in the ArrayList as well.(I think)
```

My question is there a way of making a 'new' object that has the same value as the one in the ArrayList but not modified if I change the 'temp' one.
Note: I can only use ArrayLists.

Comment: have a look [clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone())

Comment: make the object Cloneable